# Does Google display AMP search results to tablet devices?

Tags: web, responsive-design, tablet, amp-html

In implementing AMP, I need to know whether to prioritize for tablets as well as smaller mobile devices. Or, put another way, what is the max browser width that will see an AMP page? (The various breakpoints etc.)

I can't seem to find any Google docs on this.

Answer (score 2):

As of May 2016, it appears that they do not.

I've tested it on an iPad and Android tablets and while you might still get a "Top Stories" section, on the tablets this section includes results that aren't AMP where on a smaller mobile device you'd see the "Top Stories" carousel only with AMP results.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. There is no device limit in AMP. If an AMP HTML document has a configuration for a display with a specific width, that HTML AMP document will display on that device and be included in "Top Stories." Of course, the assumption here is that your `JSON-LD` includes properties sought by Google for "Top Stories." Do you have an example that supports your point?

Comment: @JayGray The question was intended to be looking specifically and when Google shows AMP-specific results in a results page. So it's not about any AMP or other spec - it's about how Google uses it and when it shows only AMP-results in their "Top Stories" or other section. Do you have suggestions for how I could reword it to make it more clear?

Comment: Sorry, but still not tracking your objective. Do you have a URL that illustrates your issue? From my perspective, the only issue related to Top Stories is the composition of the JSON-LD and the selected `@Type`. Of course, the HTML must be valid AMP, but I'm assuming you have done that.

Comment: It's less about the URL and more about the device. Do a search for anything that Google provides Top Stories for. Currently a search for the latest on "peter thiel" ( goo.gl/1as6uG ) will work. Try that on a tablet - you'll see a little "Top Stores" section. But it _won't_ be limited to results that have AMP - it's a variety of sources that Google includes. Now try that on a phone - you'll get _only_ "Top Stories" composed of AMP pages.

Comment: Simple answer: don't know what Google is doing. As far as I can tell, all mobile items also are in the full list. Speculation: Google is only showing AMP on mobile because it's a more challenging environment to display content. What's also interesting is display differences based on the browser. AMP content on Chrome mobile v. Apple mobile is different WRT word breaks and some other features. Bottom line: this is emerging tech and may/will have irregularities for a while.

Answer (score 2):

I asked a contact we have at Google about what Google considers to be a mobile device. I was told devices less than 7 inches is considered to be a mobile device and AMP is currently unavailable on tablets and won't be any time soon.